# tsql to get data files growth type in SQL 2000

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I want to know the growth type (% or MB) for database files on SQL server 2000.
I Used `sys.database_files` files on Microsoft SQL Server 2005 to get this information. I tried using `sysfiles` on Microsoft SQL Server 2000 for this, but it wasn't good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should help:

```
SELECT
  name,
  size,
  growth,
  status,
  size * 8 AS size_in_kb,
  size * 8 / 1024. AS size_in_mb,
  CASE WHEN status & 0x100000 > 0
       THEN growth 
       ELSE NULL END AS growth_in_percent,
  CASE WHEN status & 0x100000 = 0 
       THEN growth * 8 / 1024. END AS growth_in_mb  
FROM sysfiles
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query the `sysfiles` system view:

```
SELECT * FROM sysfiles
```

It will give you quite a few bits for each file including its current size, its maximum size, and the growth (plus a flag whether that growth is a fixed number of pages, or a percentage).

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260411%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for the details on what the columns are and what they mean.

Comment: Size is in pages. `size/128.0` will give you MiB including page headers. If you want MB including headers you should do `size*8192.0/1000000.0` and if you want MB excluding headers you should do `size*8060.0/1000000.0`. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190969(v=sql.105).aspx https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DBName
,groupid AS FileGroup
,fileid AS FileID
,RTRIM(NAME) AS LogicalFileName
,filename AS PhysicalFileName
,CAST(size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS Size_MB
,CAST(FILEPROPERTY(NAME, 'SpaceUsed') / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS SpaceUsed_MB
,CAST(size / 128.0 - (FILEPROPERTY(NAME, 'SpaceUsed') / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS AvailableSpace_MB
,CAST((CAST(FILEPROPERTY(NAME, 'SpaceUsed') / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / CAST(size / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 2))) * 100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS UsedPercentage
,CASE
    WHEN STATUS & 0x100000 > 0 THEN growth
    ELSE NULL
    END AS Growth_Percent
,CASE
    WHEN STATUS & 0x100000 = 0 THEN CAST(growth / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 2))
    END AS Growth_MB
,CASE maxsize
    WHEN 0 THEN 'No growth is allowed'
    WHEN - 1 THEN 'File will grow until the disk is full'
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(maxsize / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
    END AS MaxSize_MB 
FROM sysfiles
```

Just a bit more info